# Apache expands REQUEST_FILENAME with filetype

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, request

I have a .htaccess fil on a Apache22 server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

The idea is when the request is /testpage it should be rewritten to `/index.php?p=testpage`.
The problem is that apache does a write before my file, so the actually request is `testpage.xml` which actually does exists. 
Therefore, the first RewriteCond is newer true, and my rewrite rule is never applied on the `/testpage` request.

So, apache is rewriting `/testpage => /testpage.xml` before my .htaccess-files is activated. A modrewritelog does also say that the requested file is `/testpage.xml`.

There server should be a standard setup on a FreeBSD server. I know this work on other servers.

Comment: Wait, so are you requesting `/testpage` or `testpage.xml`?

Comment: Have tried to specified it. I request /testpage to the server.

Comment: You should update your post to also include the rules that do the first rewrite.

Comment: I don't know where the first rewrite happend. Then I would just have disabled it. I have solved it by adding
<code>RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]</code>

Not just the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have `Options MultiViews` on, and `mod_negotiation` is handling the request before `mod_rewrite` gets to it.